# Formula to estimate parameter in double seasonal exponential smoothing

Tags: exponential-smoothing

I have read the Taylor's Journal of double seasonal exponential smoothing, in his journal he said that the parameter of double seasonal exponential smoothing is estimate by the common procedure of minimising the sum of squared 1-step-ahead forecast errors using a non-linear optimisation routine. Can you give me the formula of it to estimate the parameter of double seasonal exponential smoothing?